# Error android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled when overlaying bitmaps

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, nullpointerexception

Im trying to overlay images on a canvas using the following method:

```
private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {

    bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(70, 70, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);  //line 179
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
    return bmOverlay;           
}
```

However, my app keeps crashing and the log reads:

java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:954)
     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:980)
     at com.MyApp.overlay(MyApp.java:179)

Can anyone help?

Comment: This happens intermittently by the way.  I am downloading images from the Internet and overlaying each one with a frame depending on certain conditions.  bmp1 is the image I download, and bmp2 is the frame I am overlaying them with.

Comment: Are you sure that bmp1 is not null?

Comment: Reading your comment now makes me do a face palm.  I will get back to you, but i believe i refer to this method in a try/catch.  In this case it should be outside my try/catch.  More details soon.  Thanks Maurits. :0)

Comment: yes, did you solve it? I am having the same issue (and a hard time testing/reproducing it)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same trowIfRecycled exception while trying to draw a bitmap to a canvas. I was trying to draw in a thread I started, before the program got around to initializing the bitmap. So in my case: bitmap was null and I had to look for a better place to do the initializing.

Answer (score 2):

Although this in an old question, I found this to be the solution for me. http://nowherenearithaca.blogspot.com/2011/06/solved-bizarre-null-pointer-thrown-in.html

where they suggest

> Try doing a clean in eclipse. It seems to be caching sometimes and can get confused. That seemed to solve it for this particular case.